# Custom dock with jquery

Tags: jquery, dock

I am attempting to create a show/hide doc with jquery. Now I am animating the top position from -200pc to 0 with this code:

```
$('#play-the-series').click(function(){
            $('#main-nav #content').animate({
                    top: '0'
                }, 1000, 'jswing');
        });
```

I need to toggle the position back to -200px to close the dock. I also want to keep the width consistent 100%.

This was the original code:

```
    $('#play-the-series').click(function(){
            $('#main-nav #content').toggle(function(){
                $(this).animate({
                    top: '0'
                }, 1000, 'jswing'),
                $(this).animate({
                    top: '-200px'
                }, 1000, 'jswing');
        }); 
    });
```

I am close with this:

```
$('#play-the-series').click(function(){
        if($('#main-nav #content').css('top', '-200px')){
                $('#main-nav #content').animate({
                    top: '0'
                }, 1000, 'jswing');
            }else{
                $('#main-nav #content').animate({
                    top: '-200px'
                }, 1000, 'jswing');
            }
    });
```

But the else statement doesn't seem to work...

Can this be done?

Comment: Can no one tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

You need `top: '-200px'`. You missed the px.

EDIT: .toggle does not do what you think it does. See [Toggle Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/). You should doing:

```
if ($('#main-nav #content').is(':visible'))
    $(this).slideDown(1000, 'jswing');
else $(this).slideUp(1000, 'jswing');
```

Comment: it still just gets sucked up to the top left corner and disappears. It seems like it is toggling show and hide not my functions.

Comment: Are you sure top was `-200px` at the start?

Comment: And what do you mean by 'sucking it up to the corner'? Can you make a JsFiddle for this?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5RWr6/  this is my first fiddle so please bare with me. New to jquery as well...

Comment: yea didn't work... Isn't :visible used to detect whether an element is display: block/none...